# why is Blade code getting rendered on the page?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I just started learning `Laravel`, Installed `Laravel 7.6.2`, and `PHP 7.4.4`
Without modifying a single line of code in the entire `Laravel` project, I try to open the `welcome.blade.php`, but it doesn't load correctly, the `Blade` code is displayed on the page as shown in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjclM.png).
Can anyone help me know the reason for this problem and how to fix it?
The next screenshots include the `welcome.blade.php` code
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETJKZ.png), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8lrf.png), and [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBi7t.png)

Comment: share your `welcome.blade.php` ?

Comment: do you want to see the code inside of the file?  @RishiRaut

Comment: Paste your code here..in your question

Comment: You don't open welcome.blade.php in the browser, you need a route that resolves to a controller action, the controller action should be set up to use that blade template to construct the actual HTML that's then served to the browser.

Comment: I edited my question to include the code as screenshots because StackOverflow didn't accept the file format

Comment: @coedycode I am very new to Laravel, I don't know what are routes and controllers

Comment: could you share your route file? also, why not read a little about how Laravel works, and then try.

Comment: @OscarDavid There are a lot of files named "route", which one do you want? also, I know I should do more research, I just thought this should work out of the box.

Comment: Please start by learning PHP, then how MVC works, then immerse yourself in Laravel's documentation.
Do not try to skip the steps, you will not succeed!

Comment: @BossCOTIGA I already have a background with PHP, but I didn't really learn MVC, maybe I need to watch some tutorials before getting to the documentation. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

How are you accessing blade file ?
doesn't seem like you are accessing it via route

Steps:

1. open terminal/cmd
2. goto your project directory
3. run `php artisan serve`
4. Open browser and type in `http://localhost:8000`

After these steps you will see the `welcome.blade.php` rendered in your browser

#### Note:

You need xamp / wamp to get apache service on your localhost

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work. I get a "This site can't be reached" message saying that localhost refused to connect

Comment: @namth I was learning from the official docs, and I already have a background with localhost and XAMPP, but apparently I need some guidance on how to run Laravel applications, thank you

Comment: @Abdullah, if you're using XAMPP as your server, you should put laravel folder into XAMPP htdocs folder, and by default, XAMPP start apache with port 80, so you can open browser with `http://localhost/your_laravel_folder` now you will see `welcome.blade.php` content rendered in HTML

Comment: @Abdullah, what is the url of https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjclM.png, in your browser

Comment: @namth http://localhost:8080/laravel-playground/resources/views/welcome.blade.php

Comment: @Abdullah, yes, that's your problem, please do not run any php file in your browser. Just `localhost:8080/laravel-playground` only, read more about https://www.tutorialspoint.com/laravel/laravel_routing.htm

Comment: @namth I kinda understood the routing explained in the Tutorialspoint link you sent me, and now I understand why I should only type the name of the project, which is to map me to the root of the project, but it still didn't solve my problem, when I type the URL you told me to go to, only the index of the directory is displayed to me.

Comment: @Abdullah, Ops, sorry, try `localhost:8080/laravel-playground/public`. but you should config `Virtual Host` for your project. I found this on google https://medium.com/@ajtech.mubasheer/configure-a-virtual-host-for-laravel-project-in-xampp-for-windows-10-d3f0068e7e1b

Comment: @namth Thank you very much, it worked but with little changes. I am using macOS, not Windows. So I didn't know how to configure a virtual host, but the steps in this video helped me, https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=633&v=DtQ8QvORMmg&feature=emb_logo basically what he did was changing the permissions for a couple of folders to be 777 . and that helped me too. Thanks again :)

Answer (score -1):

The reason why blade is because .blade.php is the template engine for laravel thus enable it writing of notation @ with if statement

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).